# FCM Push Notification are not working in IOS using Ionic Capacitor

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

Using `CAPACITOR` and `IONIC` Everything is Perfectly Works on Android but in IOS i am having Following Error:

> APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID 'mySenderId'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

```
   Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/core: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/android: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/ios: 3.2.2

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/core: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/android: 3.2.2
  @capacitor/ios: 3.2.2
```

I can see FCM Token in my `Xcode` Logs but notification are not working.

References:

> [My Issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm/issues/90)

> [Simmilar Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4687)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to register for APNS token before FCM token.

```
 PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((permission) => {
    if (permission.receive == "granted") {
      // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
      if(Capacitor.getPlatform() == 'ios'){
        PushNotifications.register().then((res)=>{
          console.log('From Regisiter Promise', res)
        })
        PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token)=>{            
          FCM.getToken().then((result) => {
            this.remoteToken = result.token;
          }).catch((err) => console.log('i am Error' , err));
        })
      }else{
        FCM.getToken().then((result) => {
          this.remoteToken = result.token;
        }).catch((err) => console.log('i am Error' , err));
      }
    } else {
      // No permission for push granted
      alert('No Permission for Notifications!')
    }
  });
```

For Latest Version of Plugin:

```
PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((permission) => {
        if (permission.receive == "granted") {

          PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
            let token = value // Push token for Android
          
            // Get FCM token instead the APN one returned by Capacitor
            if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
              const { token: fcm_token } = await FCM.getToken()
              token = fcm_token
            }
            // Work with FCM_TOKEN
            
            console.log(token);
          })
        } else {
          // No permission for push granted
          alert('No Permission for Notifications!')
        }
      });
```

Comment: Where does the FCM class come from?

Comment: https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the APNS setup and connecting it with FCM. Just follow this great tutorial:
https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

Comment: i did follow same tutorial to integrate push notification.